# jQuery form Submit with verification

Tags: jquery, forms

When creating a jQuery function to submit the form I need to first do a validation before sending the request. Here is my code:

```
$('#Form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var PhotoID = $('#PhotoID').val();
    // I will set the PhotoID to 0 just for testing.
    var PhotoID = '0';
    if (PhotoID == '0') {
        $('#GlobalError').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        return true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loader").fadeIn(2000);
            },
            success: function( response ) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When `PhotoID` is different of `0` I would like to submit the form and follow the normal page change to form action attribute. I know the opposite of the `e.preventDefault()` is the `return true;` but does not work. The function is being triggered correctly. So the problem is just about the form submit handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return false` to avoid form submit

```
$('#Form').submit(function(e){
    var PhotoID = $('#PhotoID').val();
    // I will set the PhotoID to 0 just for testing.
    var PhotoID = '0';
    if (PhotoID == '0') {
        $('#GlobalError').removeClass('hidden');
        return false;

    } else {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loader").fadeIn(2000);
            },
            success: function( response ) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But it never submit because you are setting the `PhotoID` value as 0

Comment: It worked. I marked that just for better code understanding. I will correct the code for someone with same question in the future. Thank you